# Concat comma separated firstname and lastname using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have a **users** table look like this.

```
id      name      ma_lastname

1      michael       zohans   
2       todd         butler
3       sam          pile
```

And another table named **config_project**

```
 id      pass
  1       1,3
  2       3,2
  3       2,1
```

Now i want the output look like this

```
 id               pass

  1      michael zohans, sam pile
  2       sam pile, todd butler
  3       todd butler, michael zohans
```

Comment: nicely formatted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider fixing your table structure. Normalize it.

For now, this should do (in the order of increasing user id):

```
select
    c.id,
    group_concat(concat(u.name, ' ', u.ma_lastname) order by u.id separator ', ') pass
from config_project c
left join users u on find_in_set(u.id, c.pass) > 0
group by c.id;
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b20ba/2)

Comment: I got two implementations one group_concat & other is find_in_set (first time)